# How to demonstrate V8 Weak Pointer callback?

Tags: v8, embedded-v8

I'm considering using V8 as an embedded JavaScript engine for a project but I'm having trouble figuring out how to manage the lifetime of native C++ objects.  This experiment was supposed to demonstrate the Weak Pointer callback.

Near the end of the code below I call `v8::Persistent::SetWeak` and install a callback.  All I want is to be able to create a demonstration of this callback being called.

I half-heartedly hoped it would be as easy as letting the handles fall out of scope, but the code below doesn't call the callback.  I also read somewhere that calling `Isolate::IdleNotificationDeadline` might force a garbage collection, but this didn't work either.

How can I demonstrate the weak pointer callback being called?  I'd like to write some code that will result in the the `cleanup` function being called at some point before the program exits.

I clearly am having trouble understanding how to set this up properly and would appreciate some assistance an an explanation.  I'm afraid I just don't get it yet.

My expectation is that it's possible to create a Weak Pointer via a `Persistent` handle and that when there are no more handles to an object, the callback will (eventually) be called so that native C++ resources associated with that JavaScript object can be freed.

I'm particularly put off by a comment in the v8.h header file:

> NOTE: There is no guarantee as to *when* or even *if* the callback is invoked. The invocation is performed solely on a best effort basis. As always, GC-based finalization should *not* be relied upon for any critical form of resource management!

This makes the entire engine seem useless to me for managing a native object with this mechanism.  But I'm confident there's at least some minimal contrived scenario in which the callback *is* called.

My requirement is that I am able to write some JavaScript to allocate an object that will eventually be freed when there are no more references to it.

```js
foo = createFoo(); // creates a JavaScript object wrapping the native C++ Foo object.
doSomethingWith(foo); // do stuff with the Foo here
foo = null; // make sure there are no more JavaScript handles to the wrapper for the Foo object.
// After this point, I'm hoping V8 will eventually let me know that I can delete the native C++ Foo object
```

I'm assuming I don't actually have to execute any JavaScript to demonstrate the weak pointer and cleanup mechanism.  I was hoping I could just create a `Persistent` handle and install the Weak callback then let it go out of scope.  I seem to be wrong in that assumption, or I have failed to demonstrate it here.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "include/libplatform/libplatform.h"
#include "include/v8.h"

class Foo {};

void cleanup(const v8::WeakCallbackInfo<Foo>& data)
{
  std::cout << "Weak Callback called" << std::endl;
  delete data.GetParameter();
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  std::cout << "Start..." << std::endl;

  v8::V8::InitializeICUDefaultLocation(argv[0]);
  v8::V8::InitializeExternalStartupData(argv[0]);
  std::unique_ptr<v8::Platform> platform = v8::platform::NewDefaultPlatform();
  v8::V8::InitializePlatform(platform.get());
  v8::V8::Initialize();

  // Create a new isolate and make it the current one
  v8::Isolate::CreateParams create_params;
  create_params.array_buffer_allocator = v8::ArrayBuffer::Allocator::NewDefaultAllocator();
  v8::Isolate* isolate = v8::Isolate::New(create_params);

  {
    v8::Isolate::Scope isolate_scope(isolate);
    v8::HandleScope handle_scope(isolate);

    v8::Local<v8::Context> context = v8::Context::New(isolate, NULL, v8::ObjectTemplate::New(isolate));
    v8::Context::Scope context_scope(context);

    v8::Local<v8::Object> obj = v8::ObjectTemplate::New(isolate)->NewInstance(context).ToLocalChecked();
    v8::Persistent<v8::Object> persistent;
    persistent.Reset(isolate, obj);
    persistent.SetWeak(new Foo(), cleanup, v8::WeakCallbackType::kParameter);
  }

  isolate->IdleNotificationDeadline(1.0);

  std::cout << "...Finish" << std::endl;
}
```

Note: The above code example should be built the same way the [hello_world example for V8 is built](https://v8.dev/docs/embed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a contrived example, calling `isolate->LowMemoryNotification()` should do the trick. I wouldn't recommend doing that in production though, as it's a huge waste of CPU time (unless you *really* have a low memory situation where you're close to crashing due to OOM).

Apart from that, the comment you found holds. Relying on weak callbacks to free objects is fine; relying on it for managing critical and scarce resources is not recommended. If the objects in question add up to significant size, you should use `isolate->AdjustAmountOfExternalAllocatedMemory(...)` as appropriate, to let the GC know that there is something to be freed. And you should have your own fallback mechanism to clean up everything when the `Isolate` goes away (if you're not terminating the entire process then anyway).